# SQL Update Command In Visual Studio

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-update

I'm having some trouble with UPDATE commands in Visual Studio.
I'll get right to the point.

I have a MS Access relational database back end and I have connected it in vb and I can display records and such however I can't get it to update.
I have this in Form_Load

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ContractID AS [Contract ID], ProductName AS [Product Name], SigningDate AS [Date Signed], StartDate AS [Start Date], EndDate AS [End Date] FROM ((PolicyContract) INNER JOIN Clients on PolicyContract.ClientID = Clients.ClientID) INNER Join Products on PolicyContract.ProductID = Products.ProductID WHERE PolicyContract.ClientID = '" + clientID + "' ORDER BY PolicyContract.ContractID;"

    'initialise the data adapter
    daPolicyContract = New OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, connection)
    'initialise the dataset
    dsAllroundInsurance = New DataSet
    'fill the dataset
    daPolicyContract.Fill(dsAllroundInsurance, "PolicyContract")

    'bind data grid to data in PolicyContract table
    dgvPolicies.DataSource = dsAllroundInsurance.Tables("PolicyContract")
    'autosize columns to fit grid size
    dgvPolicies.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```

It works fine, It displays the right records but I want to update the records.
When I click a button I want to update the "EndDate" value for a specific Contract. When I execute this command:

```
UPDATE ((PolicyContract) 
INNER JOIN Clients
ON PolicyContract.ClientID = Clients.ClientID)
INNER JOIN Products
ON PolicyContract.ProductID = Products.ProductID
SET PolicyContract.EndDate = '1/1/1111'
WHERE PolicyContract.ContractID = 'C100102';
```

in MS Access it Updates correctly, so the command is okay. When I try to execute the command in a click event handler like this:

```
daPolicyContract.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE ((PolicyContract) INNER JOIN Clients ON PolicyContract.ClientID = Clients.ClientID) INNER JOIN Products ON PolicyContract.ProductID = Products.ProductID SET PolicyContract.EndDate = '1/1/1111' WHERE PolicyContract.ContractID = 'C100102';", connection)
```

Nothing happens, I don't get an error but it still doesn't update. I'm pretty sure vb is executing the command but its not updating the database.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Did you execute the command? (I mean do you call daPolicyContract.Update() ?

Comment: It's a school project SQL injection vulnerability is not an issue. Yes I placed the vb update command above in a click event handler and when I click the button the command executes with no errors but if I reload the form or check the database in MS access it has not been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nowhere see the execution of the command. You have to make sure to call `ExecuteNonQuery()` on your command. Otherwise it won't get executed.

Comment: I have not executed that command. This could be the issue. Where do I execute this? And what's the syntax?

Comment: OMG that was it. Thank you!! In school we have been using command builder for update statements but I have multiple base tables so I needed to write my own. Thank you so much I had never even heard of that command.